# adjust jQuery Smooth Scroll when window resizes

Tags: jquery, fixed, smooth-scrolling, window-resize

I have a single page site consisting of several stacked divs for "pages".  The links in the nav are jumplinks to the various divs.

I'm using SmoothScroll v1.4.5 to smoothly autoscroll to the div tops when the links are clicked.

The site is responsive and has styles for 5 different widths in the CSS (1440px, 960px, 760px, 480px, 320px).  The div containing the nav is #header.  It has a fixed position and the height changes for the various widths.

The site works fine at any single size.  But when I resize the window, and the height of #header changes, the position that the autoscroll goes to for each div top gets messed up. That's because the target top is offset by the header height (remember it's fixed, with a z-index above the content) and that height is set once, at document.ready().

I need that height offset value to be reset whenever the window resizes.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="wrap" data-role="page">
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="#background">BACKGROUND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profiles">PROFILES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#culture">CULTURE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#outlook">OUTLOOK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#factsheet">FACT SHEET</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="background"><a id="background"></a>
      some stuff...
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  function getHeaderOffset(){
    var $header_offset = $("#header").height();
    return $header_offset;
  } 

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
      $header_offset = getHeaderOffset();
  if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
        && location.hostname == this.hostname
        && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
        var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
        if ($target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $header_offset;
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
            var d = document.createElement("div");
            d.style.height = "101%";
            d.style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(d);
            window.scrollTo(0,scrollTop);
            setTimeout(function() {
                d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
            }, 10);
            return false;
        });
        }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I can't figure out the right syntax to:

1) take the stuff inside of $('a[href*=#]').each(function() and turn it into a reusable function and

2) then call it inside of $(window).resize(function () {

I've tried as many ways as I can think of and have searched the forums and looked through books but everything I try just breaks the nav altogether.  Any suggestions?